# Azure DevOps: How to eliminate the warning "Tags set for the trigger didn't match the pipeline" in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, tags, azure-pipelines, warnings

I have two Azure DevOps pipelines set up so that the completion of Pipeline One triggers Pipeline Two. It works fine, but it generates an unnecessary error message.

All recent Pipeline Two builds are listed on this page (not really a link, don't bother clicking on it) : https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_build?definitionId=29

Any trigger issues are listed on this page (not really a link, don't bother clicking on it) : https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_build?definitionId=29&view=triggerIssues

It appears that every run of Pipeline One -> Pipeline Two adds this warning to the Trigger Issues page: *"Tags set for the trigger didn't match the pipeline".* It's only a warning, not an error, and Pipeline Two executes successfully. But **how can I eliminate this warning message?**

The pipeline resource is specified in Pipeline Two as follows:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeline-one
    source: mycompany.pipeline-one
    # project: myproject # optional - only required if first pipeline is in a different project
    trigger:
      enabled: true
      branches:
        include:
        - master
        - develop
        - release_*
```

No tags are specified, because tags are not used.

I have reviewed the following documentation without finding an answer. I may have missed something in the docs.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-pipelines-resource
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines

Comment: Do you have any trigger overrides specified in the pipeline definition (*not* in the YAML)?

Comment: No, both trigger override checkboxes are unchecked.